# Create CSV file with below output line

Tags: csv

I have below output line , from this line I want to create CSV file. In CSV
it should print below line as first column and in second column I want to print the string before second delemeter ":".I am using below script but It is separating data wherever "," is present , and I want to print that whole line in first column and the string after second delimiter ":" in second column .Please help me to sort data in proper format

output line :/home/nagios/NaCl/files/chk_raid.pl:token=$$value=undef;next};my($lhys,$lytrn,$ccdethe

shell script : input="out.txt"
while IFS= read -r LINES
do
#echo "$LINES"
if [[ $LINES = /* ]]
then
filename=`echo $LINES | cut -d ":" -f1`

echo "$LINES,$filename" >> out.csv
fi
done < "$input"

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I understand your question correctly.

You currently have this output

```
:/home/nagios/NaCl/files/chk_raid.pl:token=$$value=undef;next};my($lhys,$lytrn,$ccdethe
```

And you would like to have this kind of CSV output

| 2 | 3 |
| --- | --- |
| /home/nagios/NaCl/files/chk_raid.pl:token=13704value=undef;next};my($lhys,$lytrn,$ccdethe | token=13704value=undef;next};my($lhys,$lytrn,$ccdethe |

If that's what you want, you can use [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/) like this

```
echo ":/home/nagios/NaCl/files/chk_raid.pl:token=$$value=undef;next};my(\$lhys,\$lytrn,\$ccdethe" | mlr --n2c --ifs ":" cut -x -f 1 then put '$2=$2.":".$3'
```

and you will have this two columns CSV

```
2,3
"/home/nagios/NaCl/files/chk_raid.pl:token=13704value=undef;next};my($lhys,$lytrn,$ccdethe","token=13704value=undef;next};my($lhys,$lytrn,$ccdethe"
```